# How to obtain new hibernate transaction inside AsyncExceptionHandler?

Tags: spring, hibernate

1. I have 2 DB instances, say DB1 and DB2.
2. I need to write data to a table in DB2 asynchronously (`@Async` block).
3. If there is an exception while writing data to DB2, we need to write the data to another table in DB1.

I am using custom exception handler which implements `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler` (provided by Spring AOP) to catch the exception and do the operation 3. However, I am unable to do the transaction as there are two DB transactions involved and I loose the transaction. I get an error saying `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread`

I am using Spring 5.0.3 and Hibernate 5.2.11.